# IF Statement does not work on Vertx PostgreSQL pgclient

Tags: java, postgresql, eclipse, kotlin, vert.x

I have a IF statement that works in pgadmin client but not with VertX.

[image]

I got this error on VertX : [image]

The number of parameters to execute should be consistent with the expected number of parameters = [0] but the actual number is [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9pSrm.png).

Do you have an idea?
Thanks a Lot

Regards

Comment: Please replace you code picture with the actual text. See [Why not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a tuple of two parameters, `userId` and `groupId`, but your statement doesn't contain parameters, denoted with `?`

Instead of using an anonymous code block, as you do now, create a stored procedure, then bind parameters using `?`

Comment: The postgres client in vertx uses `$1`, `$2` etc instead of `?`. So that part at least looks fine to me.

Comment: @Selim I may be mistaken, hard to tell without seeing the dependencies, but judging by the syntax and the error I don't think it's https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-pg-client/java/

Comment: I think it's a bit confusing because the vertx mysql client uses `?` but if you check "Prepared queries" in the docs that you linked, you will see an example with the dollar sign.